# socket.io never connects to clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I cannot get socket.io in node.js to work. When I start my server on port 3000 it never receives a connection even occurrence when I visit `http://localhost:3000`. I even tried copy and pasting the example code from the [socket.io npmjs webpage](https://npmjs.org/package/socket.io).

**Backend**

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = io.listen(server);

app.use(express.static( __dirname + '/public'));
server.listen(3000);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('connection established');
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

console.log("Server started on port 3000");
```

**index.html**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
```

I am using socket.io v0.9.16 and express v3.4

I have extensively look on stack as well as the socket.io docs and can't figure out what is going on. This is killing me!

Note: There are plenty of "socket.io not working" questions on stack but I haven't found any that apply to my problem. The example I provided is almost literally the one from the socket.io npm reference.

Comment: Looks okay to me (also works okay for me). Try autodiscovery: `var socket = io.connect();` to see if that helps. Also, check for errors in your browsers console.

Comment: I get error this error in the browser: GET http://localhost:8989/socket.io/1/?t=1381899444325 @ socket.io.js:1659

Comment: Oh my god autodiscovery worked! Why would this be the case? I am running this on a raspberry pi, but that shouldn't matter at all. What if I wanted to send connections on several ports?

Comment: Hmm why would the client think that you're using port 8989?

Comment: Related threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051838/websockets-in-chrome-devtools | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664132/socket-io-takes-a-long-time-to-connect