# Socket.io takes a long time to connect

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm writing a node.js socket.io websockets application (version 1.3.7 of socket.io), and about 75% of the time the client takes a long time to connect to the server - the other 25% of the time it connects pretty much instantly.  I've enabled debugging on both the server and the client, and it hangs in both places at the same spot:

**Server Log**
[image: Server log]

**Client Log (Chrome)**
[image: Client log]

Eventually it will connect, and I've been able to make it connect faster by reducing the timeout from the default of 20 seconds to about 5 seconds, but I'm not sure why it's hanging in the first place.  Watching the Chrome network tab, it seems like when a connect attempt is made it will either work immediately or it won't work for the rest of the connect attempt.  So dropping the timeout to 5 seconds just means it will make more attempts faster, one of which will eventually succeed.

**Network Log (Chrome)**
[image: Network log]

In this case it took 5 connection tries, about 20 seconds, to connect.

**Client Code**

```
// client.wsPath is typically http://127.0.0.1:8080/abc, where abc is the namespace to connect to.
client.socket = io.connect(client.wsPath, {timeout: 5000, transports: ["websocket"]});
```

**Server Code**

```
var express = require("express");
var io = require("socket.io");
var htmlApp = express();
var htmlServer = http.Server(htmlApp);
htmlServer.listen(DISPATCH_SERVER_LISTEN_PORT, function() 
{
    log.info("HTML Server is listening on port " + DISPATCH_SERVER_LISTEN_PORT);
});

var wsServer = io(htmlServer, {transports: ["websocket"]});
var nsp = wsServer.of("/" + namespace);
nsp.on("connection", function(socket)
{
    log.info("connect");
};
```

We've found that clearing the browser cookies can help, but doesn't seem like a permanent solution - is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest you capture and post the contents of the network tab from the Chrome debugger so everyone can see exactly what network requests are happening and how long they are taking.

Comment: Agree with jfriend, more network traffic info is needed

Comment: Related threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051838/websockets-in-chrome-devtools | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395452/socket-io-never-connects-to-clients

Answer (score 0):

We are facing similar issue with socket IO SDK. It seems the SDK is actually waiting for the acknowledgement(util is receives the message with SID) to start messaging. But in the typical WS/WSS communication we can start messaging immediately after the connect. We are trying to tweak the SDK in such a way that it can start messaging immediately after connection establishment. Please share if any one has found a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody else still facing this error?

It is happening to a server I deployed, these are the versions:

- `"socket.io-client": "^4.5.1"`
- `"socket.io": "^4.5.1"`

Sometimes it connects instantly, but others it takes around 1~2 minutes